# Keep the retag link for 2k+ users

Tags: feature-request, edits, privileges

I have not reached 2000 in reputation yet but I have been told that the retag link is removed for 2k+ users (and reintroduced again at 10k, but in a different shape). It seems to me like it would be a good feature to keep even for 2k+ users as it is a lot smoother than having to see the whole edit page for the post if you just want to retag. As the retag functionality also bypasses the review queue it simply does not make any sense to remove it for 2k+ users.

Comment: It doesn't get removed.

Comment: @Dennis Yes it does

Comment: @Doorknob: OK, I don' see it on SO, but I get *edit tags* on SU and here. Not sure why.

Comment: @Dennis That's odd. I only have 2k on SO so I can't confirm, but this is sounding like a [bug].

Comment: And @ Daniel: 2ks can edit without going through the queue

Comment: @Doorknob: Mystery solved. It appears when you reach 10k. ([source](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/moderator-tools))

Comment: @Doorknob: Yes, but there's a lot of extras on the edit pages, so that's why I think that the retag link still would be useful.

Comment: @Dennis: Yes, it reappears at 10k but in a different shape which is just odd. This is what my feature request is about. Why does it have to go away between 2k and 10k?

Comment: @DanielHedberg: At 2k (IIRC), there's no edit *page*. Inline editing is part of the privilege.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The *retag* link is useful for users with at least 500 but less than 2000 reputation because of two reasons:

- Clicking *retag* instead of *edit* bypasses the peer review.
- The `/edit?tagsonly=true` page has information on how to retag, while the normal `/edit` page has information on how to edit, how to format, the peer review process and – of course – the Markdown preview.

Neither of the above is an advantage at 2000 rep, since you gain [full edit privileges](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/edit) (i.e., no peer review) and the ability to edits posts inline. ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DL44I.png))

Also, a *close* link gets added at 3000 rep, a *delete* link at 10k and a *protect* link at 15k. You could only delay the removal of the *retag* link, but not avoid it. There's simply not enough space.

Last but not least, having a *retag* link encourages retagging rather than editing the whole post. More often than not, an improperly tagged question has further problems.<sup>1</sup>

---

<sub><sup>1</sup> This could explain the *edit tags* button for 10k users, which *should* have learned to address all issues of a post at once.</sub>